# What caused a new caulking job around a tub to develope pin holes within hours

Tags: caulking

please help... I had a contractor replace old caulk around my bathtub yesterday. Last night I noticed a small pinhole which at first looked like a speck of dirt, Today there are several more pinholes, and the one that I noticed last night is now larger today. I notified the contractor and he tried to say I got the caulk wet or tried to clean it which did not happen. I knew that it would take at least 24 hours before I could run water in the tub or take a shower.  This guy is adamant that I did this...
I would like to know what caused these small pinholes.. To me, it looks like the caulk lines are too thin and when it dried, it separated causing the pin holes.

Comment: Can you add a few pictures so we can see what you see?

Comment: is it humid in the bathroom?